# pytorch std must more than or equal to 0.0

Tags: pytorch

I tried to use **torch.normal** but got the error that shows std >= 0.0; I need to fix this error.

```
b=32
n_s = 10
dim = 64
slots_mu = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1, dim))
slots_log_sigma = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1, dim))

mu = slots_mu.expand(b, n_s, -1)
sigma = slots_log_sigma.expand(b, n_s, -1)

slots = torch.normal(mu, sigma)
```

and it raised an error below

```
---> 10 slots = torch.normal(mu, sigma)

RuntimeError: normal expects all elements of std >= 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the definition of standard deviation, std is for distance measurement, please take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710614/why-is-the-standard-deviation-always-positive).

To solve your problem, converting `std` to absolute value can help:

```py
slots_log_sigma = nn.Parameter(abs(torch.randn(1, 1, dim)))
```

Comment: @MalodyGamor if this answer can solve your problem, please mark it as correct.